# Как запустить два одинаковых бота в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Есть рабочий бот discord.py, пытаюсь запустить такой же в параллели (с другим токеном) - получаю

> RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

Код:

```py
import discord
import threading

from config import tokens

fbot = discord.Client()
sbot = discord.Client()


def new_bot_instance(bot, token):
    bot.run(token)

@fbot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{fbot.user.name} ready")

@sbot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{fbot.user.name} ready")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_bot_thread = threading.Thread(target=new_bot_instance, args=(fbot, tokens[0]))
    #second_bot_thread = threading.Thread(target=new_bot_instance, args=(sbot, tokens[1]))
    first_bot_thread.start()
    #second_bot_thread.start()
    first_bot_thread.join()
    #second_bot_thread.join()
```

Как исправить?

Comment: `self bots` запрещены `TOS`

Comment: каким образом это относится к ответу на мой вопрос?

Comment: Я не отвечал, это комментарий

Answer (score 0):

Треды не нужны - боты асинхронны.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(fbot.start(tokens[0]))
    loop.create_task(sbot.start(tokens[1]))
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        loop.run_until_complete(fbot.close())
        loop.run_until_complete(sbot.close())
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

Comment: Если использовать `sbot.start()`, то оба бота появляются в сети, но ни один не выполняет `on_ready()` и не реагирует на команды.
Если изменить на `sbot.run()`, то работает только первый запущенный.

Comment: "не реагирует на команды" - run_forever() выполняется или проигнорировали часть ответа?

Comment: боты остаются в сети на протяжении работы скрипта и отладчик доходит до `run_forever()`, так что скорее всего выполняется.

Comment: да токен забыл похоже

Comment: если бы я забыл токен, то боты даже в сети не появились бы + запуск без токена выдает ошибку, а так просто пустая консоль

Comment: пустая консоль это нормально. надо посмотреть исходники